# What are the numbers, triangles, and flags opposite the comments?

Tags: support

What are the numbers, triangles, and flags opposite the comments?

I have looked through the available topics among the Help pages. I have done a search on Meta and reviewed 9 of the 17 pages of results. I cannot find an answer, although this must be explained somewhere on these pages.

I ask because now and again I am nicked for two points for no apparent reason. The loss of points often seems to have something to do with the comments.

Answer (score 2):

**Triangles** are for upvote and downvote respectively.

The **numbers** display the accumulated score of the votes (two upvotes and one downvote = score 1). With sufficient reputation, which you have, you can also click on the score to see the breakdown of upvotes and downvotes (on posts). Comments do not have downvotes.

Mind, upvotes give +10 reputation points whereas downvotes only give -2 reputation points, so that's what you observed. Comments do never influence your reputation. If you click on the little cup with the star and click the notification for the -2 reputation, you'll notice it links to a post proper, not a comment.

**Flags** indicate a possible or actually cast flag.

Comment: Thank you! Now what is the clock symbol underneath the post’s score, and what is the badge with the star?

Comment: By the way, today my score was increased by 14  after I gained 30 points for an answer. I don’t understand this one at all.

Comment: @MarkAndrews clock: show post history. Badge: turn this into favourite (follow each change), increase by 14 sounds like two or seven downvotes being reversed due to deletion of the accout or serial voting

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry to bother you about this, but I truly could not find an answer.

Comment: I just got dinged one point for no apparent reason, and with no explanation.  I am really really really tired of this nonsense.

Comment: @MarkAndrews One single point is the standard for casting downvotes, which come at a cost.

Comment: So who did I downvote?

Comment: @MarkAndrews If you click on the small cup in the navigation menu on the top of the page you should see links to any post because of which a reputation change occurred. It could well have been involuntarily, in which case you could click once more in the arrow down to retract the vote if that wasn't your intention.

Comment: I just got 8 points for an answer that shows 0 votes. What is going on?

Comment: @MarkAndrews Quite obvious, isn't it? One upvote, one downvote = score 0 and +8 reputation received. If you click the score of the post you can see that for yourself. Upvote received +10, downvote received -2, downvote cast -1. See [this help center site](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).